# Torrent video streaming app that supports subtittles

Tags: bittorrent, video-player

I'm looking for a Windows desktop app that allows watching videos from torrent without the need to download them. I'd appreciate a functionality that automatically finds subtitles for a movie. If not, then it should at least allow subtitles to be loaded from srt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application allowing you to watch videos from torrent is [WebTorrent Desktop](https://kubadownload.com/webtorrent-desktop-download.1411.html).

> WebTorrent Desktop is an app designed to instantly stream audio and video files. WebTorrent fetches file pieces from the network on demand for instant playback... support for subtitles in .srt and .vtt format.

Another option that can stream torrent movies and automatically download subtitles is [Powder Player](http://powder.media).